# svg why dasharray is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm very new in SVG and animation. I read some tutorials online and I would like to achieve a "drawing" icon effect in order to have a loading image:
https://www.cassie.codes/posts/creating-my-logo-animation/#heading-svg-stroke-dasharray

I have created a codepen with my paths. I apply to it a dasharray but it doesn't have the same effect than in tutorial and I don't understand why

The SVG was generated from Avocode (design from my designer).

https://codepen.io/JeromeLam/pen/pooYPwp

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="test2" fill="#fe5915" d="M12.17 43.373H1.756A1.036 1.036 0 01.72 42.337V15.915c0-.28.112-.547.313-.742L16.008.592c.193-.189.452-.294.723-.294h10.416a1.036 1.036 0 110 2.072h-9.995L2.792 16.352V41.3h9.379a1.036 1.036 0 010 2.073z"/>
  <g>
    <path class="test3" fill="#fe5915" d="M27.597 36.145c-3.477 0-6.742-1.138-8.734-3.044a1.036 1.036 0 111.433-1.497c1.615 1.546 4.345 2.468 7.301 2.468 2.977 0 5.716-.932 7.328-2.493a1.036 1.036 0 011.441 1.49c-1.989 1.926-5.267 3.076-8.769 3.076z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="test4" stroke="000000" stroke-width="4" d="M13.207 16.243l13.94-13.572 13.94 13.572v24.948h-27.88zm29.952 25.984V15.806c0-.28-.113-.547-.313-.742L27.87.483a1.036 1.036 0 00-1.446 0l-14.976 14.58a1.04 1.04 0 00-.314.743v26.421c0 .573.464 1.036 1.037 1.036h29.952c.572 0 1.036-.463 1.036-1.036z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
path.test4 {
  stroke-dasharray: 20;
}
```

Comment: Because your `stroke` is invalid, since `000000` is not a valid color value ...?

Comment: Besides the commented by @04FS Your path is a complex path with a hole in the middle. What you are seeing is the path filled with black. Please use this `d="
M13.207 16.243l13.94-13.572 13.94 13.572v24.948h-27.88z"` for the `.test4`

Comment: @enxaneta the path you are giving to me is to fill the house and not the line to draw the house. You can try it in the provided codePen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented: Your path is a complex path with a hole in the middle. What you are seeing is the path filled with black. You can't see the dashes because you are seeing the fill. In order to see the dashes you may need to simplify the path like so:

```css
path.test4 {
  stroke-dasharray: 20;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="test4" stroke="#000000" fill="none" stroke-width="4" d="M13.207 16.243l13.94-13.572 13.94 13.572v24.948h-27.88z"/>
</svg>
```

The `d` attribute I'm using is the first part of what you have. I've deleted everything from the `m` command to the end. The removed part is drawing the "hole"

Comment: Cool, thanks. If I can, do you use a tool or something to make it "human readable" ? Or maybe it's because I'm totally new in SVG world

Comment: I'm not using any tool but you can add line breaks to your d attribute before any letter command. this may help you a lot.

Comment: Ok I will make some try. Actually I have the lines that are not on the same Y coordinate ... ^^

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. Please show mi the code and tell me more

Comment: https://codepen.io/JeromeLam/pen/rNNRXvy I'm trying to "redraw" more simply the icon but I don't understand why I don't have aligned lines at the top.

Comment: Because the other paths are also complex paths. To understand what happens I advise you to add different colors of fill and stroke. In order to fix it you'll need to rewrite the paths